# c++ threadsafe ringbuffer implementation

Tags: c++, thread-safety, circular-buffer

I am doing multithread programming in C++ and I am wondering whether there is a thread-safe implementation of ringbuffer in C++ or do you have any idea how I can implement it.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743605/thread-safe-implementation-of-circular-buffer answers your question

Comment: Are you looking for the special case when only one thread writes and another thread reads?  Or do you want a general solution?

Comment: Implementing any thread safe container is relatively easy, unless of course performance is your driving factor.  What exactly is it that you're looking for?

Comment: I do not know the difference but I am interested with one writing and one reading thread. Performance is important for me.

Comment: Ring buffers are relatively simple, if incrementing head and tail are atomic, then you're 99% on your way to thread safety.  What platform?  (Windows/Linux)?  Boost available?

Comment: I am using POSIX threads under linux. I am not using Boost.

Comment: Is `C++11` available?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html is probably what you're looking for

Comment: Read this book, it will help: https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770

Comment: Ring Buffers where one thread is reading and one thread is writing are inherently safe if one thread only ever updates the write marker and one thread only ever updates the read marker.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a basic implementation.  Requires objects stored in the buffer to be default constructable, and copyable (by storing them in a std::vector<>).  Requires `C++11` support (for `std::atomic`).  Most any recent version of `gcc` will have it with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`

If `c++11` isn't available, substitute the appropriate compiler intrinsic for making `head_` and `tail_` atomic.

Should be safe for one reader thread and one writer thread.

Publish items by calling:

```
  auto val = ringbuffer.back();
  val = some_value;
  ringbuffer.push();
```

Retreive items by calling:

```
  auto val = ringbuffer.front();
  // do stuff with val
  ringbuffer.pop();
```

If `back()` returns a `nullptr`, then the buffer is "full".  If `front()` returns a `nullptr` then the buffer is "empty".

Warning, not tested (at all) :D

```
  #include <vector>

  template <class T>
  class RingBuffer
  {
  public:
     RingBuffer(size_t buffer_size)
        : ring_(buffer_size)
        , buffer_size_(buffer_size)
        , head_(0)
        , tail_(0)
     {
     }

     T* back()
     {
        bool received = false;

        if(available(head_, tail_))
        {
           return &(ring_[head_ % buffer_size_]);
        }

        return nullptr;
     }

     void push()
     {
        ++head_;
     }

     T* front()
     {
        if(tail_ < head_)
        {
           return & ring_[tail_ % buffer_size_];
        }

        return nullptr;
     }

     void pop()
     {
        ++tail_;
     }

     size_t size() const
     {
        if(tail_ < head_)
           return buffer_size_ - ((tail_ + buffer_size_) - head_);
        else if(tail_ > head_)
           return buffer_size_ - (tail_ - head_);

        return 0;
     }

     bool available()
     {
        return available(head_, tail_);
     }

  private:
     bool available(uint64_t h, uint64_t t) const
     {
        if(h == t)
           return true;
        else if(t > h)
           return (t - h) > buffer_size_;
        else// if(h > t)
           return (t + buffer_size_) - h > 0;
     }

     std::vector<T> ring_;
     const size_t   buffer_size_;
     std::atomic<uint64_t> head_;
     std::atomic<uint64_t> tail_;
  };
```

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by "If c++11 isn't available, substitute the appropriate compiler intrinsic for making head_ and tail_ atomic."

Comment: `head_` and `tail_` need to be atomic, meaning that modifying (or reading their values) should be an atomic operation.  If you don't understand what that means, then I think you're probably not ready for multithreaded programming.

Comment: Hmmm.  Not sure I get this.  Isn't eg `size` vulnerable to `push` being called from another thread and changing the value of `head_` between the `if` and `return`?

Comment: Size is correct at the time of the entry (to that function) from one thread.  Two subsequent calls to size may return different values.  It is untested though.

Comment: I don't think this is threadsafe at all as you could call front() or back() at any point in time, hang onto the pointer and modify the underlying data.  To make it thread safe I think you would either need to provide "push(somedata)/pop" and wrap access to ring_ in a mutex internally or wrap all access to this class in a mutex externally.  I'm no expert, but I don't think the atomics are really doing anything to guard the data itself currently.